# How to clear browser cache in protractor

Tags: css, protractor, browser-cache, angularjs-e2e

I want to validate css color change in my e2e using protractor.
I can see the color is changed in DB, but it is not reflecting in the UI, I tried to clear the cache using

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(protractor.Key.F5).perform();
```

but still it is not bringing up the changes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies().then(() => { console.log("cleared") } );
```

Add this to your test.

For clearing local storage

```
browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();')
```

Comment: Will this clear the cache before each test? Because I don't want to clear that all the time, I just want to clear only in this particular test

Comment: You can add it in a single test also.

Comment: How to add in a single test?

Comment: Just add this line in your it block

Comment: No luck
The result is 

And I logout,

And I clear cache,

"cache cleared"

Then The Reset password button should reflect the defined colour,
    × failed,
      AssertionError,
          + expected - actual,

          -rgba(54, 95, 145, 1),
          +rgba(255, 192, 203, 1)

Comment: Then try clearing local storage.  browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();')

Comment: I tried both the,
browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.clear();");
browser.executeScript("window.sessionStorage.clear();");
but no luck